# What is the meaning of "modulo" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, usage

> "Could we run Unix on that [AM3 computer architecture],
>   i.e. reuse existing software as-is on the simple cores **modulo**
>   recompiling the source code?" (Poss & Koening, AM3 towards a hardware Unix accelerator for many-cores, 2015)

I don't understand what the author means by *modulo* in the above snippet. It doesn't seem to mean the mathematical modulo operator, but I don't find another definition on the Internet.

Comment: This isn't an answer because I don't understand that either. I looked at the article, and my best guess as to the meaning of the full sentence is "Could we run an existing version of Unix on a computer system with many small cores, rather than on the types of systems currently in use with one or possibly a few large cores?"

Comment: I don't understand the sentence, and I don't understand the explanation given in the only answer this question has so far (and I have a Master's in Computer Science, and am a native speaker of U.S. English for many years). I think the use of the word in the sentence could best be described as "poor".

Answer (score 8):

The mathematical definition is the source of this more idiomatic usage. The modulo operation partitions integers into equivalence classes, e.g.  `5 modulo 4 = 1` means "in the world of modulo 4, 1 is the same as 5".

In the example, different software systems are deemed in the same equivalence class; the need to recompile the source is deemed irrelevant. You could replace modulo with "with the exception of" or "ignoring the need for" in the example to get a similar meaning sentence.

Comment: [The New Hacker's Dictionary](http://www.catb.org/jargon/) has two definitions that match your explanation:  "[modulo](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/modulo.html)", and Definition 2 of "[mod](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/mod.html)".

Answer (score 4):

It's quite common for engineers to use the term *mod* (or *modulo*) to mean "not counting" (or "except for").  It means something that is small enough to not change the main answer, it's just a detail.